# How to access properties from a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an api call that produces the follow results in the console (after pairing it down using map()  ).

```
{…}
​
CHANGE24HOUR: "$ 11.16"
​
CHANGEDAY: "$ 3.31"
​
CHANGEPCT24HOUR: "6.73"
​
CHANGEPCTDAY: "1.90"
​
FROMSYMBOL: "Ξ"
​
HIGH24HOUR: "$ 183.38"
​
HIGHDAY: "$ 183.38"
```

However, no matter what I try I can't get at it's properties. The object is called 'coinStats'.

I have tried the following:

```
coinStats.HIGHDAY = undefined
coinStats['HIGHDAY'] = undefined
coinStats["HIGHDAY"] = undefined
```

Tried to convert it to an array to see if that would help using

```
Object.values(coinStats)  // Would not work
```

I am sure the answer is so simplistic. But I am just not sure what it is?

The original raw api results are in the following shape:

```
(1) […]
​
0: Object { CoinInfo: {…}, RAW: {…}, DISPLAY: {…} }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: [
```

The info I am looking for is in DISPLAY -> USD. I used a map() function to return that sub-object.

The code I am using to fetch the data is essentially the following:

```
const API = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?tsym=USD&page=1';

fetch(API)
  .then(results => results.json())
  .then(coinData => {

    const view = coinData.Data.filter(obj => { return obj.CoinInfo.Name === TRX});

  })

const coinFeedAbridged = view.map(item => item.DISPLAY.USD);

const coinStats = coinFeedAbridged[0];

console.dir(coinStats);
```

I can't access coinStats.HIGHDAY for example... I get 'undefined'.

Comment: How does your "api call" work? What do you do to retrieve it and what is the shape of the object?

Comment: Try: `console.log(coinFeed)` and post the output.

Comment: That's exactly what I have above. Well... that is from console.dir(coinFeed).

Comment: It could be that they are non enumerable, non-writable properties. Check what the output is of `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(coinFeed, 'HIGHDAY')`. It could also be that the object is frozen: check `Object.isFrozen(coinFeed)`

Comment: I dont see the keys of the object being separated by commas?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt, it is console output.

Comment: @trincot: I tried what you suggested and it returned 'undefined'.

Comment: @phoenixson copy paste the response in a separate local file and check if your fetching of object code is working properly.

Comment: Looking at the output from console.dir(coinFeed) I can see all the info I am looking for so I believe the fetching code is working.

Comment: It is hard guessing if we don't have code with which to reproduce the problem. One other thing is that the console also shows inherited properties, which could lead to an explanation. But there can be so many things going on... We need a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the core code elements that I am using to fetch the data.

Comment: How do you get the variable coinFeed in your code?

Comment: Sorry I have removed that. I am using React so I have taken the 'state' stuff out of it but left some variables in there by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The fetch call is async, so you can't access the `view` variable until the call is finished. The code calls the async function and runs the next line, so `view` variable will be undefined. You have to handle the data inside the fetch callback function, where the data is known.

```
const API = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?tsym=USD&page=1';

  fetch(API)
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(coinData => {

      const view = coinData.Data.filter(obj => { 
        return obj.CoinInfo.Name === 'TRX'
       });

      const coinFeedAbridged = view.map(item => item.DISPLAY.USD);

      const coinStats = coinFeedAbridged[0];
      console.log(coinStats);

    })
  }
```

You can test it out in this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gran7ptk/1/

Comment: I am already able to view the whole object. I just am not able it access it's properties. Although in your Fiddle you used JSON.stringify() and is something I will look into it.

Comment: I'm using JSON.stringify() to show it on the screen, you can change it to console.log and you will see the object in the console.

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/gran7ptk/2/, I'm accessing `coinStats.HIGHDAY` there

Comment: That's great but I would like to extract the separate properties within the render() function rather that using setState() to pass one property. What would that code look like?

Comment: You can store the whole object in the state and access its properties in the render method.
https://jsfiddle.net/gran7ptk/3/

Comment: That solved it. I guess it was a React issue rather than a general JS issue. How do I credit your answer. I guess I can rewrite the question and make it a React question.

Answer (score 0):

Change line - Add inverted commas to Text "TRX".

```
 const view = coinData.Data.filter(obj => { return obj.CoinInfo.Name
 === TRX});
```

to
const view = coinData.Data.filter(obj => { return obj.CoinInfo.Name === "TRX"});